# Can I disable two-finger scrolling mode on touchpad?

Tags: 16.04, touchpad

Is it possible to configure the touchpad so that I can have two fingers on it without being scrolling?

I'm used to having my left index finger resting on the left button while scrolling but now it locks the mouse.

Comment: How would you like to scroll instead?

Answer (score 1):

Open "System Settings", go to "Mouse & Touchpad", go to the Touchpad section, and then disable "Two-Fingers scrolling":

[image]